# LAN data from computer

Tags: data, networking

I have an HMI (Siemens MP 377) to print collected data on a LAN connected printer.

Now I would like that the data that are being sent to the printer is also received at a computer through Ethernet LAN. The HMI however has a single LAN port.

I have done some research on the internet already. Now the problem is that whether I should use LAN switch or HUB to copy the data so that both printer and computer receives the same data? Following, how would I visually see what is coming to the computer (or printer, because they both are receiving the same data)?

Answer (score 1):

Since I don't know anything about the Siemems MP377 (what does it do and how its connected to the printer e.g. through a hub or with a direct crosslink cable), one way i could go is using a sniffer (See topology in the following image ).

[image]

That way, you make sure that the data sent to the printer remain the same, and you get a copy of the data to another PC. The main problem then will be to somehow decode the data.

The latter part (decoding the data and presenting it in a meaningful manner), is the most difficult. The first part can (probably) be done with a computer with two cards and a software like Wireshark.

Answer (score 1):

As stated by @NMech, I would suggest using a sniffer. I am assuming your connections are something like the following.

[image]

I would use [wireshark](https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/Ethernet) which a very popular open source tool used by network engineers. There is plenty of online support.

Below is a screen capture of data traffic.

[image]

Reference:

- [How to Capture an IPDS Trace in AS400/OS400 Environments (2011)](http://support.lexmark.com/index?pmv=print&page=content&locale=en&userlocale=EN_US&id=HO3616)
- [Spy on Your "Buddy's" Network Traffic: An Intro to Wireshark and the OSI Model](https://null-byte.wonderhowto.com/how-to/spy-your-buddys-network-traffic-intro-wireshark-and-osi-model-0133807/)